# VBScript if, do, while test not working right

Tags: vbscript

```
'Assign name, age, phone number, address, and birthday variables

WScript.Echo ("Please Enter Employee's name")
name = WScript.StdIN.ReadLine
If name = Null then
Wscript.Echo ("You must Enter Employee's Name")
Do While name = nothing
    WScript.Echo ("Please Enter Employee's name")
    name = WScript.StdIN.ReadLine
Loop
End If
```

This is my vbscript code trying to test for name variable to be null and if empty loop til not empty.

Comment: You are checking name for equality against both `Null` and `nothing`; I don't think both of these conditions can be true simultaneously.
Also, shouldn't it be `Do While name Is Nothing`?
http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinoscript/nothing_empty_null/

Comment: Name is a empty string. So `Loop Until Name <> ""`. `Empty` refers to an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @Noodles simplest check is `Do While Len(Trim(name & "")) < 1`. Avoid all the `Nothing`, `Empty` and `Null` fiasco!.

Comment: That introduces a function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code below and ran it as `cscript test-input.vbs` which seems to do what you want.

test-input.vbs

```
'Assign name, age, phone number, address, and birthday variables

WScript.Echo ("Please Enter Employee's name")
name = WScript.StdIN.ReadLine
Do While name = ""
    WScript.Echo ("Name is required - Please Enter Employee's name")
    name = WScript.StdIN.ReadLine
Loop
```

Comment: @Mouseman I'd be inclined to do something like `Do While Len(Trim(name & "")) < 1` to avoid when someone enters `{space}` in the input line.